# Как сделать поддержку в aircrack-ng кириллицу?

Tags: linux, wifi, decrypt

У меня есть словарь паролей с русскими символами, но aircrack-ng не производит подборку. Как тогда можно реализовать поддержку unicode aircrack-ng?

Answer (score 0):

Cмотрим стандарт IEEE Std 802.11i-2004 LOCAL AND METROPOLITAN AREA NETWORKS

траница 166 раздел H.4.1

...
— A pass-phrase is a sequence of between 8 and 63 ASCII-encoded characters. The limit of 63 comes
from the desire to distinguish between a pass-phrase and a PSK displayed as 64 hexadecimal
characters.

`— Each character in the pass-phrase must have an encoding in the range of 32 to 126 (decimal),inclusive.`
...

Таблица ASCII, символы с 32 по 126 включительно могут быть в пароле, и никаких других.

**Так что если  роутер и поддерживает русские буквы в паролях - это прямое нарушение производителем стандарта 802.11i**

Как вариант пробуй что то типа вот этого  - https://aishamaliki.blogspot.com/